# Compute the covariance of $R_2 R_1^T$ where $R_2$ and $R_1$ are rotation matrices with Gaussian uncertainty

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I have estimates of two 3x3 rotation matrices $R_1$, $R_2$ expressed in terms of their expected values $R_{1\mu}$ and $R_{2\mu}$ and covariances $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$. The latter are expressed in the Lie algebra for SO(3). That is:

$$
R_1 = R_{1\mu}\exp(\omega_1) ~~~~~~~ \omega_1 ~\tilde~ \ N(0,\Sigma_1)
$$

$$
R_2 = R_{2\mu}\exp(\omega_2) ~~~~~~~ \omega_2 ~\tilde~ \ N(0,\Sigma_2)
$$

where $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are independent random variables, exp is the exponential map from so(3) to SO(3), and $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$ are 3x3 covariance matrices.

I want to compute an expectation and covariance for $R_{\Delta} = R_2 R_1^T$, expressed again as an expected rotation matrix and 3x3 covariance in the Lie algebra for SO(3). I do not expect that this quantity is actually Gaussian-distributed so I am happy with an approximation based on an appropriate linearization.

Note that I am *not* guaranteed that $R_{\Delta}$ is close to the identity.

Comment: Did you try a Monte-Carlo simulation, i.e. generate $\omega$, compute $R_\Delta(\omega)$ and then average out over many samples to get a feel what you are getting?

Comment: As the question is currently stated, the expectation is $R_{2\mu}R_{1\mu}^T$ and the covariance is zero, since $R_\Delta$ has the constant value $R_{2\mu}R_{1\mu}^T$ independent of $\omega$. Did you intend the two instances of $\omega$ to be two different, independent random variables?

Comment: @joriki - yes, my bad, fixed now

Comment: @Sasha - yes, thanks. I am convinced that the problem set up is reasonable but I'm still keen to find an analytic expression.

Comment: @Alex: The information that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are independent is still missing in the question. As it's currently stated there's not enough information to determine the expectation and covariance of $R_\Delta$.

Comment: @Sasha: Apologies again! I believe the question is now clear.

Answer (score 1):

We can compute the resulting covariance matrix by using [first order uncertainty propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Non-linear_combinations) (applying the chain rule when necesary):

$$
\Sigma_\Delta = 
J^{R_2 R_1^T}_{R_2} \Sigma_2 (J^{R_2 R_1^T}_{R_2})^T  +
J^{R_2 R_1^T}_{R_1^T} J^{R_1^T}_{R_1} \Sigma_1 (J^{R_1^T}_{R_1})^T (J^{R_2 R_1^T}_{R_1^T})^T
$$
where:

- $J^{R_2 R_1^T}_{R_2} = R_1$
- $J^{R_2 R_1^T}_{R_1^T} = I$
- $J^{R_1^T}_{R_1} = -R_1$

(see eqs. (140)-(142) of [Solà's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01537.pdf)).

In conclusion (unless I've made some mistake):

$$
\Sigma_\Delta = 
R_1 (\Sigma_2 + \Sigma_1) R_1^T 
$$

You probably want to test it against a monte carlo simulation to check it's correct.